# Как при создании таблицы задать столбец с датой создания записи по умолчанию?

Tags: sql, oracle

При создании таблицы необходимо в столбец `cr_date` указать, что в нём при создании записи должна сохраняться непосредственно дата создания записи.

Пробовала следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE svod 
(.....
 cr_date DATETIME DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
 .....
);
```

Но SQL Developer на это выдает ошибку:

> Error report - ORA-00902: неверн.тип данных 00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"

Так же пробовала через getdate следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE svod 
(.....
 cr_date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
 .....
);
```

Ошибка следующая:

> Error report - ORA-00904: "GETDATE": недопустимый идентификатор 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid dentifier"

Подскажите, как в таком случае корректно указывать столбец?

Comment: date, а не datetime

Comment: даже если я указываю date, ошибка остается прежней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот два способа указать дату и время создания записи и [оба работают](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d403d87d3e0a1169f99d6d39c33e760):

```
create table svod (
    createdt date default sysdate,
    createts timestamp default systimestamp
);

Table SVOD created.
```

Comment: В обоих случаях отдает ошибку:
ORA-00902: неверн.тип данных
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"

Comment: Не верю. Поместите [сюда](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f64f9e1ed04d3b8ca5842c7bd28f8d4e) то,  что вы запускаете и дайте обновлённную ссылку.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b77006a04d27f33c5352d8cd0c7fbba8

Comment: Спасибо, я разобралась в чем была проблема, не уследила немного за синтаксисом в других полях.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Правда сложилось впечатление, что ответ для вас был не очень полезным.